# When limiting the height of the block - the last line inside the block is cut off ugly

Tags: html, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify attribute height="149" (equals style="height: 149px;") for v-card.

But then the last line inside the v-card is ugly cut off.

How to prevent it?

```
  <v-card dark height="149">
    <v-card-title class="text-h5">
      Unlimited music now
    </v-card-title>

    <v-card-subtitle>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <br />
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </v-card-subtitle>
  </v-card>
```

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/overclocked/pen/rNoOGyJ?editors=1000

[image: Example]